# Sentencia "else if" no funciona

Tags: r

Tengo esta función para procesar una base de datos que estoy utilizando, el tema es que el resultado solo clasifica todo como "público" y parece no detecta la otra condición, ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
sectorlaboral = function (funcionariopublicoinstitucion) {
  if(becal_completo$funcionariopublicoinstitucion!="NO")
    return("publico")
  else if(becal_completo$funcionariopublicoinstitucion=="NO")
    return("privado")
}
```

La variable es "pertenencia a una institucion publica" entonces las respuestas son o "no" o el nombre de la institucion. Como tengo que calcular la cantidad de personas pertenecientes al sector privado y al publico estoy creando una nueva columna que clasifique los no como privado y lo demas como publico.

Comment: Es efectivamente código R? en cuyo caso te sugiero que compartas una muestra de los datos de `becal_completo`, por ejemplo con `dput(head(becal_completo))` y lo agregues a tu pregunta.

Comment: Ahora agregue mas info de que se tratan los datos que quiero procesar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventualmente no necesitás hacer una función nueva para lo que buscas, puede utilizar la función base [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
becal_completo$Institucion <- ifelse(becal_completo$funcionariopublicoinstitucion == "NO", "privado", "publico")
```

Comment: Dale, lo probare!

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion, por si sirva a alguien, el problema era como indique mi variable dentro de la funcion, no hacia falta hacer referencia al dataframe con $:

```
sectorlaboral = function (funcionariopublicoinstitucion) { 

  if (funcionariopublicoinstitucion=="NO" | funcionariopublicoinstitucion=="NO ")

    return ("privado")

 else 

    return ("publico")
}
```